# mvc3 jquery client custom validation not running

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to get client side custom validation working for the last two days now on ASP.Net MVC3. I've followed the examples [here](http://johnmj.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/unobtrusive-custom-validator-for-mvc3/), [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425718/jquery-custom-validation-problem-in-mvc-3) but cannot get it to run. Could someone take a look at my (current) code and please let me know if you see any errors, any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Web.Config has both ClientValidationEnabled & UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set true

_Layout.cshtml references files as follows

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DateFormatValidator.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The server side validation class is defined as follows

```
public class DateFormatValidation : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string ValidDateFormat { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "validatedate",  // the name of the validation rule as specified in DateFormatValidator.js
            ErrorMessage = LocalisationStrings.InvalidDateFormat
        };

        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters["name"] = ValidDateFormat;
        yield return modelClientValidationRule;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {            
        var dateString = (string) value;
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateString))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // if we can't convert to a date based on the current culture then we will get a null back from the ConvertLocalDateFormatToISO extension method
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateString.ConvertLocalDateFormatToISO()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(LocalisationStrings.InvalidDateFormat);
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

The view model is defined as follows

```
public class SearchViewModel : ElectronicDocument
{

    #region Properties

    [DateFormatValidation(ValidDateFormat="validatedate")] // addig the paramter to the attribute is just a test to get this to work
    public string DueDateFrom
    {
        get;            
        set;             
    }

    [DateFormatValidation]
    public string DueDateTo
    {
        get;
        set;             
    }
```

The client side validation script is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.addMethod('validatedateformat', function (value, element, param) {
    if (!value) { return true; }
    try {
        var isValidDate = false;
        /* - CheckDateValidFormat is available from the base controller class  */
        $.get('CheckDateValidFormat(' + value +')',
            function (data) {                  
                isValidDate = data;
            });
        if (isValidDate) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('validatedate', ['name'], function (options) {
    options.rules["validatedateformat"] = options.params.name;
    if (options.message) options.messages["validatedateformat"] = options.message;
});
```

} (jQuery));

Finally the view looks as follows:

```
<td style="font-size:10px; white-space:nowrap; color: #666">               
           @Html.TextBox("DocumentDateFrom", Model.DocumentDateFrom, new { @class = "date", style = "width:90px;" })
        to @Html.TextBox("DocumentDateTo", Model.DocumentDateTo, new { @class = "date", style = "width:90px;" })</td>
```

Comment: Should that first `return false` be in the 'client-side validation script'? Surely it will never reach the code underneath beginning with `try` as it's unreachable?

Comment: sorry - I added that just to check if the script was getting run at all, removed now - still no improvement

Comment: Where is the code that contains the action `CheckDateValidFormat` and can you see it being hit in your development IDE

Comment: @SpaceBison - nope CheckDateValidFormat is never hit

Comment: So I reckon the route to your controller action in the $.get is wrong - if you switch to $.ajax and add an `error: function() { etc etc }` block it might help you work out what the issue exactly is, if not immediately obvious, but I think you need `/area/controller/action` or something along those lines.

Comment: Alternatively, it *could* be the datatype expected on the parameter, but I think this is less likely.

Answer (score 2):

You are including `jquery-1.8.11.min.js`. This version of jQuery doesn't exist, as the latest version is 1.7.2.

I suspect you are including **jQuery UI** (latest version 1.8.20) and you think that's **jQuery**. Make sure you're using correct files.

Comment: Thanks Jakub - I've updated that now to 1.7.2 but still no go